# html5 canvas draw multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i am trying to make a function that shows the last move of my 'players', but when i try it shows no errors and/or lines. this is my code:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
ctx.drawImage(backgroundImg,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height)

for (var i = 0; i < team1X.length; ++i) {
    ctx.drawImage(playerImg,X[i],Y[i])
}

//this part doesn't work
for (var i = 0; i < X.length; ++i) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(LastX[i],LastY[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(X[i],Y[i]);
        ctx.stroke();
}
```

`X`, `Y`, `LastX` and `LastY` are arrays with 11 numbers.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no obvious error in your code, but there might be errors in the code around it, like how you initialize the data and how you call the draw event. Please follow [this guide to create  a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is syntactically correct. Nothing wrong with it. However, you will need to add a bit of context to your question and do some debugging on your own, make sure you are instantiating the `ctx` variable correctly and that `X` and `Y` contains the desired data. Here's a working minimalistic example:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvasElement');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var X = [10,20,30,40,50,60];
var LastX = [50,140,230,320,410,500];
var Y = [10,90,30,40,50,60];
var LastY = [10,90,30,40,50,60];

for (var i = 0; i < X.length; ++i) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(LastX[i],LastY[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(X[i],Y[i]);
        ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasElement" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```